# HTML/CSS Fixed background content follow foreground content that has dynamic height

Tags: html, css, sass

I've set up a content wrapper that displays certain content as background, and overlays it with more (main) content on the foreground. I've achieved this using absolute positioning, and you can have a look at the recreation of the issue and situation I have here: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/heyimsam/pen/KZqJgr)

**Let me explain:**

I have a carousel set up in the background and it works perfectly, and in the foreground content I have a table, that is displayed over it. However, this table is a dynamic data table, and if the content is **longer** than the height of the screen (on page load, the height of the whole wrapper and background carousel and respective images are set to 100vh), then the table overflows the height of the image and the whole container, **now this is fine and intended**, but I wish for the background to be fixed and follow the dynamic height of the foreground content, then to stop being fixed at the end of the content, and then scroll more to display the rest of the content of the page as normal.

**I've tried**:

1. Making the background position fixed dynamically and removing fixed property once user has scrolled to below the content, but this doesn't work as the background jumps back up all the way, displaying how the table overflows onto the rest of the content (so it doesn't stay where it was scrolled to but unfixed)
2. Googling and searching on StackOverflow, but to no avail as either I can't search using the right terms for this, or I'm missing something out and people usually don't have a problem with this.

**I am not worried about mobile-compatibility either mobile browser or screen sizes, so feel free to suggest stuff that won't be mobile compatible.**

**Edit 1**: added "that has" before "dynamic height" in title

```css
.jumboContent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 15%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  color: white;
  .desc {
    width: 40vw;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    h1,
    h2 {
      position: relative;
      top: 35%;
    }
  }
}

#parallax {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  .bgContent {
    transform: translateZ(-1px);
  }
  .content {
    transform: translateZ(0);
  }
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.4);
  font-size: larger;
  th {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
  td {
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }
  .name {}
  .flag {
    max-height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: -7px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="parallax">
  <div class="bgContent">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1920x1080/?coffe">
  </div>
  <div class="content jumboContent">
    <table align="center">
      <tr>
        <th align="left">ID</th>
        <th align="left">Name</th>
        <th align="left">Age</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Yahoo</td>
        <td>21</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br><br>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet taiyaki yr ea in pug tbh food truck minim vinyl copper mug officia street art cupidatat excepteur DIY. Organic tattooed eiusmod, seitan jean shorts asymmetrical pour-over. Slow-carb minim adaptogen, echo park exercitation intelligentsia
  dolore wayfarers edison bulb schlitz. Umami do mixtape, disrupt cronut pop-up ethical chicharrones yr tumeric. Polaroid actually pickled, yuccie eu vegan organic kinfolk ullamco. Shoreditch portland cronut irony, synth dolor activated charcoal fugiat
  vinyl glossier small batch consequat austin bushwick hexagon. Street art jean shorts copper mug ut. Taxidermy keffiyeh proident jianbing hexagon cold-pressed four loko literally. Taxidermy affogato ut cardigan occaecat. Everyday carry ex hell of pok
  pok cred jean shorts unicorn pug yuccie labore vice gluten-free. Hella in marfa meggings pour-over. Est brooklyn VHS irure tbh. Humblebrag raw denim ethical, irony try-hard offal bicycle rights listicle fixie hot chicken occupy. Lumbersexual veniam
  put a bird on it taxidermy umami neutra ex semiotics sed la croix officia dolor fanny pack. Taxidermy brooklyn seitan enim jianbing, esse lorem actually photo booth direct trade sed swag lo-fi neutra.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the `<img>` with another div which has position absolute

```
<div class="imgBackground"><img src="...">
</div>
```

look at this link

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OzgqqJ?editors=1100

Comment: This is actually very close to what I need, but (i should have mentioned earlier, my apologies) in my case I would prefer it much more if the same effect is achieved **without** 2 scrollbars on the y-axis.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, for some reason changes to `position` property to fixed or absolute, makes no expected changes.